# Reference typedef documentation from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to reference a typedef created in a base controller within extending controllers to limit duplication of documentation.  My end goal is to declare a few common use documentation objects in the base controller that can be shared with all extending controllers.  My current environment is Node v8.9.1 with VS Code as my IDE.  My project is running stock ES6 without Babel or TypeScript setup.  I'm assuming that my use case is supported and that I simply am missing how to "include" documentation from other files.  I have tried using module, see and link from jsDoc3 without much luck.  At its core, here is the file layout I'm attempting

base.controller.js

```
/**
* Get list request
* @typedef ListRequest
* @type {Object}
* @property {ListRequestQuery} query
*/

/**
* Get list request
* @typedef ListRequestQuery
* @type {Object}
* @property {number} pageNumber - Page to start returning from, default is 1
* @property {number} pageSize - Limit number of results to be returned, default is 10
*/
class BaseController {
  constructor () {
  }
}
// rest of file left out for brevity
```

If I attempt to use ListRequest within BaseController I can see my property types and everything works as expected.  However, if I attempt to use the ListRequest typedef in an extending file Node only shows type "any" for req within VS Code

extending.controller.js

```
/// <reference path="base.controller.js" />
const BaseController = require('./base.controller')

/**
 * @extends BaseController
 */
class ExtendingController extends BaseController {
  constructor () {
    super()
  }

  /**
  * Get contact list.
  * @param {ListRequest} req

  */
  async list (req, res, next) {
  // rest of file left out for brevity
```

Comment: Please note that the right word isn't "typedef" but "class".

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but I am intentionally speaking about typedef, which is used in defining objects in documentation. I will update my question to be more clear